# Obtener campos con llave foránea en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Buen Dia
Estoy batallando con la logica de una consulta hacia **SQL SERVER** el escenario es el siguiente:
Tengo una tabla `tbl_solicitud` con los campos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo otras dos tablas que son `tbl_usuario` y `tbl_cliente`, Necesito extraer la informacion del nombre del usuario basandose en su ID y el nombre del cliente basandose en el ID del cliente

```
tbl_usuario.correo <-- correo es el nombre de mi campo en la tabla
tbl_cliente.nombre <-- nombre es el nombre de mi campo en la tabla
```

Se me dificulta la logica, ¿podrian explicarme? Intente el `INNER JOIN` pero se me va la onda a mitad de camino al armar los `WHERE`

Necesito un `SELECT * FROM tbl_solicitud WHERE estado = 'abierto' <- pero con el correo del usuario y nombre del cliente`.

Comment: Hola EduardoVelazquez,podrias poner lo que has intentado con los inner join, para que podamos darte una mejor explicación de lo que has realizado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurriria algo como esto:

```
SELECT tbl_cliente.Nombre, tbl_usuario.correo, tbl_solicitud.estado
FROM  tbl_solicitud
INNER JOIN tbl_usuario
ON tbl_usuario.idusuario = tbl_solicitud.idusuario
INNER JOIN tbl_cliente
ON tbl_cliente.idcliente = tbl_solicitud.idcliente
WHERE tbl_solicitud.estado = 'abierto'
```

Comment: por favor agrega una explicación a tu respuesta, considera que no solo el OP la utilizará si no todos aquellos usuarios presnetes y futuros; entonces lo ideal es que comprendan que hiciste

Comment: Listo muchísimas gracias, solo tuve que agregar los demás campos faltantes de mi tabla tbl_solicitud. Entiendo que no debo utilizar temrinos ambiguos sino referenciados "tbl.campo"  los inner buscan la relacion de mi tabla usuario en el campo id con la llave foranea y asi con la tabla cliente. Asi lo entendi, estudiare la sentencia para poder entenderla mas facil.